# Perl getpwuid() and getpwnam()

Tags: perl, unix, passwords

I'm learning perl's *nix system tools and I've been staring at the following two sentences for several minutes:

> You can think of getpwuid() and getpwnam() operators as *random access* -- they grab a specific entry by key so you have to have a key to start with. Another way of accessing the password file is *sequential access* -- grabbing each entry in some apparently random order.

I'm 99% sure this is a typo, but if it isn't I'm clearly missing a key idea. Can anyone shed some light on the subject?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a typo, but very poorly worded.  `getpwuid` looks up a passwd entry by UID.  `getpwnam` looks up a password entry by name.  These are "random access" like system memory is "random access"; you can pick which one you want by providing a *key*.  (For system memory, the "key" is the address.  For `getpwuid`, the key is the UID.  For `getpwnam`, the key is the name.)

These are in contrast to `getpwent`, which simply returns the "next" entry from the passwd file.  The entries will be returned in some unspecified order.  This is "sequential access", like reading a file from disk.  Although for `getpwent` you do not know what order the results will appear.

The wording is confusing because they use the word "random" for both the phrase "random access" (like a memory) and "apparently random order" (by which they mean "unspecified order").

They should have said "unspecified order" or "indeterminate order" rather than "apparently random order".

Comment: Thanks! Would it be rude to recommend the author the other book I'm reading? It's called <i>The Essentials of Interaction Design</i>

Comment: @Yitzchak:  I think sending them a suggestion for improvement would be a fine idea.